# SQLite query running successfully in version 3.5.2 but giving error in version 3.7.11 - using aggregate functions

Tags: objective-c, sqlite, ios6

My query was working fine in Sqlite 3.5.1 version but when I run the same query in 3.7.11 version am getting misuse of aggregate function min() error. Below one is my query. Please help me in this regard

select distinct category from m_ipaperdara  order by min(displayorder) asc

Answer (score 1):

`DISTINCT` is not a grouping that can be used for aggregate functions.
If you want take the smalled `displayorder` in each category, you have to explicitly group by that column:

```
SELECT category FROM m_ipaperdara GROUP BY category ORDER BY MIN(displayorder)
```